# Toggle other specific classes off when toggling one on

Tags: jquery, class, toggleclass

I have a set of `div` elements that are not children of one another and each have individual background images, and therefore use individual class names.

When clicking on one I want it to highlight by swapping its background image. If another `div` is highlighted I want to un-highlight it by swapping its background image back. If the same highlighted `div` is clicked I want to un-highlight it.

My current method is to do this via `toggleClass` and I've managed to swap the class of a `div` I've clicked on, but not to swap the others back.

I've managed this before with `div` elements that all swap to the same class by using the `.not` feature, but I'm struggling to do this with `div` elements that use individual, specific classes.

JSFiddle version here: https://jsfiddle.net/el_simmo/8cnu776j/3/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var theboxes = $("#svg1 #svg2 #svg3");
    var clickclasses = $("svg1classclick svg2classclick svg3classclick");

    $("[id^='svg']").on("click", function(){
        var thissvg = $(this);
        var svgclick = $(this).attr("id") + "classclick";
        thissvg.toggleClass(svgclick);
        theboxes.not(thissvg).removeClass(clickclasses);
    });
});
```

Comment: Put a common class on all the SVG containing divs.

Comment: `$("#svg1 #svg2 #svg3")` this is selector for only 1 element. Not for 3. `$("svg1classclick svg2classclick svg3classclick");` This one too, and here you have syntax error. If that is a class the dot (.) is required, because its css selector`$(".svg1classclick .svg2classclick .svg3classclick");`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can massively improve your logic and DRY up your code with the use of common classes. Firstly, apply a common class to all the `div` elements you want to be clickable, in my example I user `svgContainer`:

```
<div>
    <div id="svg1" class="svgContainer"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="svg2" class="svgContainer"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="svg3" class="svgContainer"></div>
</div>
```

From there you can use the following much simpler logic to toggle the highlight on and off with a single `highlight` class:

```
$(".svgContainer").on("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
    $('.svgContainer').not(this).removeClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
.svgContainer { 
    height: 60px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#svg1 {
    background-image: url("http://fdslive.oup.com/www.oup.com/elt/general_content/global/measuring_impact/images/svgs/teacher.svg");
}
#svg1.highlight {
    background-image: url("http://fdslive.oup.com/www.oup.com/elt/general_content/global/measuring_impact/images/svgs/teacher-purple.svg");
}
#svg2 {
    background-image: url("http://fdslive.oup.com/www.oup.com/elt/general_content/global/measuring_impact/images/svgs/student.svg");
}
#svg2.highlight {
    background-image: url("http://fdslive.oup.com/www.oup.com/elt/general_content/global/measuring_impact/images/svgs/student-purple.svg");
}
#svg3 {
    background-image: url("http://fdslive.oup.com/www.oup.com/elt/general_content/global/measuring_impact/images/svgs/support.svg");
}
#svg3.highlight {
    background-image: url("http://fdslive.oup.com/www.oup.com/elt/general_content/global/measuring_impact/images/svgs/support-purple.svg");
}
```

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8cnu776j/7/)

Note the use of compound class selectors in the CSS means you only need to toggle a single class, which makes the JS code a lot simpler.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you Rory and Josh! That works great, think I'll have to brush up on my CSS AND JQuery...  I understand all the code here but one thing I'm not so sure on is the second argument in the toggleClass.  I'm guessing it's the switch parameter that uses the 'allowHighlight' variable as its boolean?

Comment: Thats right: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/, although I updated the logic in there to be a little cleaner without it.

Comment: Oops, just seen the changes, ignore the last bit of that last comment

Answer (score 0):

You should use a common class between the elements. In this case, I used the class `.clicked` for the highlighted elements and `.svg-wrapper` for all of the elements. In doing so, you can easily select the elements as well as add/remove the class from the elements.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/gfqfm3c1/)

```
$('.svg-wrapper').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    $('.svg-wrapper').not(this).removeClass('clicked');
});
```

Then you can update your CSS to style the clicked variants:

```
#svg1 {
    /* Initial background */
}
#svg1.clicked {
    /* Clicked background */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I change the background image on one common class when each element uses a different image?